Impossible to pass disabledDates in react-native-date-ranges
I am trying to disable specific dates in the React Native Date Range. Despite trying various methods, I am unable to find the correct way to disable dates. Here is what I have tried so far:
My Setup:
I am using the react-native-date-ranges package in my React Native project. The goal is to disable certain dates so that users cannot select them.
I try those two different way of writing:

<DateRangePicker
  ...
disabledDates={[ new Date(2024, 6, 22) ]}
disabledDates={[ moment("2024-07-22").format("YYYY-MM-DD") ]}
disabledDay={(date) => moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') === '2024-07-22'}
  ...
/>

Here is the full code of component :
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import DateRangePicker from "react-native-date-ranges";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/fr";
import { Colors } from "../constants/styles";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

moment.updateLocale("fr", {
  weekdaysMin: moment.weekdaysMin().map((day) => day.toUpperCase()),
  months: moment
    .months()
    .map((month) => month.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + month.slice(1)),
});

const DatePicker = ({ mode = "range", onConfirm, disabled, availableDates }) => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const locale = i18n.language;
  moment.locale(locale);
  const datePickerRef = useRef(null);

  const disabledDay = (date) => {
    const formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    // return !availableDates.includes(formattedDate);
    return formattedDate === '2024-07-22';
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => !disabled && datePickerRef.current.setModalVisible(true)}
        style={[styles.datePickerButton, disabled && styles.disabledButton]}
        disabled={disabled}
      >
        <Ionicons name="calendar" size={25} color="#fff" />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <DateRangePicker
        ref={datePickerRef}
        onConfirm={(range) => onConfirm(range)}
        onCancel={() => datePickerRef.current.setModalVisible(false)}
        mode={mode}
        style={{ height: 0, width: 0 }}
        locale={locale}
        markText={t("Select Date Range")}
        selectedBgColor={Colors.primary100}
        disabledDates={[ moment("2024-07-22").format("YYYY-MM-DD") ]}

        customStyles={{
          placeholderText: { display: "none" },
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.primary100 },
          contentText: { display: "none" },
          headerMarkTitle: { color: "#fff", fontSize: 25, opacity: 1 },
        }}
        customButton={(onConfirm) => (
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                const selectedRange = datePickerRef.current.state;
                if (!selectedRange.startDate || !selectedRange.endDate) {
                  alert(t("No dates selected"));
                  return;
                }
                onConfirm();
              }}
              style={styles.confirmButton}
            >
              <Text style={styles.confirmButtonText}>{t("Submit")}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => datePickerRef.current.setModalVisible(false)}
              style={styles.cancelButton}
            >
              <Text style={styles.cancelButtonText}>{t("Cancel")}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  datePickerButton: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary100,
    borderRadius: 10,
    elevation: 2,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
  },
  disabledButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  confirmButton: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary100,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  confirmButtonText: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  cancelButton: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  cancelButtonText: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});

export default DatePicker;

Thanks a lot
